# Como usar o useRef corretamente com o react no ionic5?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou usando as seguintes dependencias:

Ionic/react: 5.0.7
React: 16.13.0
typescript: 3.8.3

Eu possuo um select:

`<IonSelectOption ref={refExemplo} {..propsDeExemplo }>{textoDeExemplo}</IonSelectOption>`

E sempre que eu clicar em botao qualquer eu quero limpar o texto selecionado, mas sem perder o state. Normalmente apenas com o React (em javascript) basta atribuir um `ref` ao select e dps limpar ele assim:

`refExemplo.value = null;`

Mas com o Ionic eu nao consigo atribuir nenhum valor.

Para capturar o texto desejado eu faco:
`frenteRef.current?.textContent`

Mas quando eu tento limpar a opcao selecionada da seguinte forma: `frenteRef.current?.textContent = ""`

eu recebo:

> The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.

Alguma forma de atribuir/limpar o texto desse select ?

Comment: se estiver usando um estado para esse componente é por ele que deve ser alterado? tem o código completo?

Comment: Qual estado ? Eu gostaria de limpar a opcao selecionada quando clicar no botao sem mudar as opcoes, que no meu caso, estao armazenada em um estado

Comment: Mas o estado é para isso mesmo, agora limpar ficou estranho ... pela referencia não é ideal ...

Comment: Eh, como eu tava usando o state em number, ao setar ele como 0 ele perde a referencia como eu queria, foi mais simples do que eu esperava, coloca uma resposta sobre isso pra eu marcar =)

Comment: Você mesmo pode explicar o problema e marcar como resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim como @Virgilio comentou, usar o ref pra esse caso não é o ideal. Resolvi o problema zerando o estado responsável por armazenar o valor do select. Isso funcionou porque os possiveis valores estão nas `IonSelectOption` então ao zerar o valor, a opção selecionada fica zerada.

Em um input de texto creio que o workaround deve ser um pouco diferente.